# Configure Firebase analytics in iOS app cause crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-analytics

Configure Firebase analytics in iOS app cause crash when kill and restart the app.

Configure: App delegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method [FIRApp configure]

> Error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[FIRA_AppDelegate-1471511968204 configureWatchdelegate]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance XXXXXXXX'

Comment: @NickCatib I don't have feature in app which support watchKit. So watchKit configuration & delegate does't suppose to implement.